# exception using the `apply` method on a `CudaTensor`

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

This problem emerged only after trying to use torch's CUDA capabilities instead of relying to the CPU.

I'm trying to initialize a `CudaTensor` of weights of a convolutional neural network. The function is the following:

```
function fill_0normal(t,sigma)
  t:apply(function() return torch.normal(0,sigma) end)
end
```

and it's invoked in the following way:

```
fill_0normal(m.weight, sigma)
```

with `m` being a convolutional module, `m.weight` being a `CudaTensor` and `sigma` is a floating point value.

The exception that I get is the following:

```
/hpc/sw/torch7-2016.02.09/bin/luajit: invalid arguments: number number 
expected arguments: *CudaTensor* [float] [float]
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x2aaaaf63e040
    [C]: in function 'func'
    /hpc/sw/torch7-2016.02.09/share/lua/5.1/torch/FFI.lua:117: in function 'apply'
    /hpc/sw/torch7-2016.02.09/share/lua/5.1/cutorch/Tensor.lua:3: in function 'apply'
    setup_model.lua:4: in function 'fill_0normal'
    setup_model.lua:16: in function 'init_conv'
    setup_model.lua:43: in function 'init_module'
    setup_model.lua:90: in function 'initializeNetRandomly'
    assignment3-cifar10.lua:49: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../torch7-2016.02.09/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406010
```

Any ideas on what might cause it?

I also tried to convert the value returned by `torch.normal` into
a 1-element `CudaTensor`, but it didn't help.

Comment: I see no CUDA kernel code, CUDA toolkit/libraries, or CUDA runtime errors in this question. The fact that the lua compiler is generating an invalid argument error on a call to a framework which has baked in CUDA support in a backend doesn't automatically mean this question, as written, has anything to do with CUDA. If you were using cutorch wrappers for CUDA APIs directly and having problems, or getting a CUDA runtime error, it might be appropriate to tag this as a CUDA question. But you are clearly not, and thus, this isn't a CUDA question.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call :normal on the tensor.

```
function fill_0normal(t,sigma) do
  t:normal(0, sigma)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solved the problem. But unfortunately, it's still not clear why the original code was not working. Any ideas?

Comment: because you used apply wrong. look at the apply function signature: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#self-applyfunction